# update object key in react array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

why is this so difficult to do or find an answer for?

I have my state

```
state: {
   people: [
     {name: 'tom'},
     {name: 'rich'},
   ]
}
```

why is it so hard to update the name Tom to Pete for example?

```
const people = this.state.people.slice();
people[i].name = value;
this.setState({ people });
```

I can do this but 1) `i` is undefined and 2) it just seems messy

is there not a more elegant solution to update object keys??

Comment: I was also going to ask about `i`, do you have a requirement to update all the names or at a certain index?

Comment: just need to update the name for that particular record when i click on it

Answer (score 0):

If you try to rename first element you need to pass integer index:

```
const people = this.state.people.slice();
people[0].name = value;
this.setState({ people });
```

If you need rename element specify by `name` tom, use for example es6 .findIndex method:

```
const people = this.state.people.slice();
const index = people.findIndex(item => item.name === 'tom');
if(index >= 0) {
  people[index].name = value;
}
this.setState({ people });
```

Answer (score 0):

you aren't looping though anything so yes `i` is undefined.

lets say you have a click handler for an item..

```
{this.state.people.map( (person, idx) => <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, idx)>Person here!</div>)}
```

now from here you have an index to update the record from...

then your person to update you can get in the handle function `const person = {...this.state.people[idx]}`

notice i make a new object here for the person so were sure to not mutate a state object directly. assuming you have another value or state variable somewhere you can then assign that value to that person

EDIT:

```
handleClick = (idx, e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const robots = [].concat(this.state.robots);
    const robot = robots[idx]
    robot.name = value;
    robots[idx] = robot;
    this.setState({robots})
}
```

Comment: im very confused. your way works but I still get error saying it `cant read e of undefined`

  `updateRobotName = (index) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target; //the e here
    const newRobot = {...this.state.robots[index]}
  }`

but when I remove this line, it then doesn't work?? and when I pass `e` into the function, it still doesn't work??

Comment: I would love to help but I need to see code or more of what is going on to give a good / correct answer

Comment: ok John, try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/x9q84po70o. how would I update those names in the state?

Comment: @TheWalrus ok cool, yea so you just need to mutate the robot object, assign to the robots array and set that as state. i make a new object signature for the array so that way you aren't mutating state directly. see here https://codesandbox.io/s/olwwj0xmw9 .... if you have any more questions dont hesitate to ask! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are printing name in JSX as below

```
const { people } = this.state;
return people.map((person, index) => {
    <p
        onClick={() => {
            const newPeople = people.slice();
            newPeople[index] = 'some calculation to find new name';
            this.setState({ people: newPeople });
        }}
    >
        {person.name}
    </p>
});
```